# Find unmatched strings in 2 columns within sumif

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A contains below data:

```
  Jon
  Tina
  Dan
  Mj
  Tyler
  Tim
  Sarah
```

Column S contains below data:

```
  Dan
  Sarah
  Ron
```

I'm using below function to get sum from column M by matching names in column S615 to S617 with those from column A which is working correctly.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(M:M, A:A, S615:S617))
```

Now, I need to find sum product of all those which are not matching from column S meaning I want to exclude all those from column A which are present in column S615 to S617. I tried NOT function around S615:S617 but that didn't work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: I guess not. I'm using Excel 2019. But I'm still open to solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum the entire column then subtract the matching result you already got:

```
=SUM(M:M)-SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(M:M, A:A, S615:S617))
```